# AlertDialog doesn't disappear after validation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment where an alert dialog is displayed so that the user can choose to create a resume or a job.

But after the registered user creates a resume or vacancy, I want the alert dialog to be dismissed, but it continues to appear. And how to make if the alert dialog appears, nothing can be seen behind it and is it possible to change the design of the alert dialog buttons

```
package com.example.finder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Fragment_Finder extends Fragment {

     MyResume resume;
     MyVacancy vacancy;
     private static final int CREATE_RESUME_REQUEST = 1;
     private static final int CREATE_VACANCY_REQUEST = 2;


     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        CreateApp();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__finder, container, false);

    }

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> createResumeLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Получаем данные из Intent
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    if (data != null) {
                        // Обновляем значение resume
                        resume = data.getParcelableExtra("resume");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
      
     registerForActivityResult(
     
     ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> createVacancyLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // Получаем данные из Intent
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    if (data != null) {
                        // Обновляем значение resume
                        resume = data.getParcelableExtra("vacancy");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
      public void CreateApp(){

        if (resume == null && vacancy == null) {
            // Создаем диалоговое окно
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
      
            builder.setTitle("Что вы желаете?")
                    .setItems(new String[]{"Создать резюме", "Создать вакансию"}, new 
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            if (which == 0) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), 
     Create_ResumeActivity.class);
                                createResumeLauncher.launch(intent);
                            } else {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), 
     Create_VacancyActivity.class);
                                createVacancyLauncher.launch(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            builder.create().show();
        } else {
            // Отображаем данные о резюме или вакансии
        }

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you assigned 2 getParcelableExtra values to one variable.

See what you mistakes

```
if (data != null) {
                // Обновляем значение resume
                resume = data.getParcelableExtra("resume");
            }
```

And

```
if (data != null) {
                // Обновляем значение resume
                resume = data.getParcelableExtra("vacancy");
            }
```